# Maximum call stack size exceeded using angular ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I want to redirect after login to /dashboard

```
        $scope.submit = function (user) {
        if ($scope.loginForm.$valid) {
            UserService.login(user).then(
                function (result) {
                    $location.path('/dashboard');
                }, function (reason) {
                    $scope.msg = "username or password is not correct";
                });
            $scope.reset();
        }
    };
```

in app.js I want to create my menu dynamically and show dashboard.html

```
        $routeProvider
        .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
            abstract:true,
            resolve: {
                menu: function (MenuService) {
                    return MenuService.getMenu();
                }
            },
            controller: function ($scope, menu) {
                $scope.menu = menu;
                $scope.oneAtATime = true;
            }
        })
```

and in dashboard I use ng-view to load my template

```
<div class="content">
<div class="container">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

but it catch "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

[image]

THE MenuService servie return promise

```
factory('MenuService', function ($q, $http) {
var getMenu = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/menu', 1).
        success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).
        error(function (data, status) {
            deferred.reject(status);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
};

return{
    getMenu: getMenu
}
```

})

I changed the MenuService.getMenu() to this:

```
        $routeProvider
        .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
            abstract:true,
            resolve: {
                menu: function (MenuService) {
                    MenuService.getMenu().then(function(result){
                        return result;
                    });
                }
            },
            controller: function ($scope, menu) {
                $scope.menu = menu;
                $scope.oneAtATime = true;
            }
        })
```

and now dashboard is loaded but without menu. then method is called after dashboard.html loading!!!!

when I remove ng-view every thing work perfectly.

What is my problem?
thank you

Comment: what `reset` method contains?

Comment: I add the MenuService service

Comment: Could you add code of `reset ` method

Comment: I edit the post and added service that get menu from server,you mean the server handler? now I have a new problem ,I use then to get data from promise and now dashboard.html load but without menu,because then function is called after dashboard loaded

Comment: your resolve should return promise of `MenuService.getMenu()` like this `resolve: {
                menu: function (MenuService) {
                    return MenuService.getMenu().then(function(result){
                        return result;
                    });
                }
            },`

Comment: I edit this post,I do exactly that you said.(please see the latest code in post)  . but it does`t work

Comment: take a look at my answer ..that should work

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do change in your custom `resolve` service code. Currently your controller promise has receiving chain promise, so you should return a `promise` instead of return `chain promise`.

**Code**

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        abstract:true,
        resolve: {
            menu: function (MenuService) {
                return MenuService.getMenu();
            }
        },
        controller: function ($scope, menu) {
            menu.then(function(data){
                $scope.menu = data;
            });
            $scope.oneAtATime = true;
        }
    })
```

Comment: my first code was this , It cause  Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @farhad look at my udpated answer

Comment: it cause an error:"TypeError: menu.then is not a function"

Comment: it should work because `getMenu`  is returning promise

Comment: the problem of  Maximum call stack size exceeded is that my controller call multiple time.It drives me crazy

Comment: @farhad looks like you are calling `/dashboard` route multiple times